# Binding r-value to l-value reference is non-standard Microsoft C++ extension

Tags: c++, resharper, rvalue, lvalue, resharper-c++

I've been working on a project recently, and I decided to install ReSharper C++ to Visual Studio. When it analysed my code it spat out a bunch of new warnings (apparently I have bad coding habits..). One of them that took me a while to figure out was `Binding r-value to l-value reference is non-standard Microsoft C++ extension`. I've recreated the warning with the following code:

```
Type foo(Type t1, Type t2) {
    return Type(t1.value & t2.value);
}
```

The expression `t1.value & t2.value` triggers the warning. I understand the second part of the warning, which means that my code only compiles due to a Microsoft extension, and other compilers would refuse to compile it. I'm using an overloaded operator, which returns an object (called `Datum`) which `Type` takes as a constructor parameter, as a reference (`Type::Type(Datum& dat)`).

With some playing around, I managed to make the warning go away by refactoring the code:

```
Type bar(Type t1, Type t2) {
    Datum datum = t1.value & t2.value;
    return Type(datum);
}
```

To my understanding, this is functionally equivalent to the code that generated the warning. What I'd really like to know is whether there's something here that I should be aware of, because I'm pretty confused about why one function complains and one doesn't.

*I think I've got it figured out. I already had the question typed out, so I'm going to post it with what I found, for the reference of others. I don't really have enough knowledge to go into detail, so please feel free to expand on or correct my answer if it isn't satisfactory :)*

Comment: What is `Type::value` supposed to be? How does it support the binary `&` operator?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. `Type::value` is an object of the class `Datum`, which holds an array of bytes. It's similar to an individual data type. When you apply the binary `&` operator, the operator is applied to all of the bits, just as it would be if you used it on an integer, for example.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34240794/1971003

Answer (score 8):

That's one way to remove the warning: the variable is an *lvalue*, so can bind directly to the dodgy constructor's reference parameter, while the expression result is an *rvalue* which can't.

A better solution is to fix the constructor to take its argument by value or constant reference:

```
Type(Datum dat)         // value
Type(Datum const & dat) // constant reference
```

Now you can give the argument as either an *lvalue* or an *rvalue*.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, the reason I got such behaviour is because the `Type` constructor is taking a *reference* to the `Datum` object, rather than passing it by value. This causes a warning in `Type foo(Type, Type)` because the compiler doesn't like taking the reference of expressions, which would be due to the semantics of expression evaluation.

*Again, please feel free to elaborate on or correct my findings, as this is simply the result of my experimentation and inference.*