# Why does a friend operator require const-ness on its operands while a member operator does not?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

This may be related to the fact that [taking references to temporary objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34240886/5936187) is allowed only in some situations, but I'm not sure how this rule applies.

In this example, the compiler stops at line `a + b + c` because `a + b` returns an `Int`, to which a reference must be taken in order to evaluate `(a+b) + c`. According to what I've read, this is a deliberate choice so temporary values aren't mutated. The way to fix this code is to change the signature to `Int operator + (const Int & a, const int & b)`.

```cpp
struct Int {
    int a;
    Int() { a = 0; }
    Int(int i) { a = i; }
    friend Int operator + (Int &, const Int &);
};

Int operator + (Int & a, const Int & b) {
    return Int(a.a + b.a);
}

int main() {
    Int a, b, c;
    a + b + c;
    return 0;
}
```

However, if we change the operator from being a `friend` function to being a struct member, then this code, which should have the same problem with creating a temporary mutable value, actually compiles:

```cpp
struct Int {
    int a;
    Int() { a = 0; }
    Int(int i) { a = i; }
    Int operator + (Int &);
};

Int Int::operator + (Int & v)
{
    return Int(a + v.a);
}

int main()
{
    Int a, b, c;
    a + b + c;
    return 0;
}
```

Why exactly does this happen? These two situations seem mostly identical, but in the latter, not only is `const`-ness not required for the RHS value, it's not required for the LHS value either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case, the code is effectively equivalent to:

```
operator+(operator+(a, b), c);
```

Here, the expression `operator+(a, b)` is an *rvalue*, which cannot be bound to a *non-const lvalue reference*.

In the second case, we have:

```
a.operator+(b).operator+(c);
```

There is no such problem, since only *lvalues* `b` and `c` are bound to that *non-const lvalue reference* parameter.

---

As @BenVoigt pointed out, you may wonder about calling a non-const member function on a temporary. This is perfectly legal. There is a special rule about it in the Standard, which is described in detail in the @dfrib's answer.

Comment: The question is making the point that `(a.operator+(b))` is bound to a non-const hidden `*this` parameter

Answer (score 3):

### Summary:

Try `a+(b+c)` and watch your member version fail.

C++ has named values (aka lvalues, named because they are values that make sense on the LEFT hand side of an `=` assignment) and temporaries (aka rvalues, which go on the RIGHT hand side of an `=` assignment).  (this paragraph contains simplifications).

lvalues will bind to non-const references, while rvalues will only bind to const references.  So `Int&` won't bind to a temporary, while `Int const&` or `const Int&` (same thing) will.

The error you are getting is that `a+b+c` is parsed as `(a+b)+c` by the order of operations in C++.  And the result of `a+b` is a temporary (an rvalue).  So it won't bind to `Int&`.

A method like `Int operator+(Int& rhs)` takes `*this` as the left-hand argument to `+`, and `rhs` is the right-hand argument.  So `(a+b)+c`, `a+b` is `*this` and `c` is `rhs`.  Member `operator+` works on temporaries, so all is good.

A friend like `Int operator+(Int&, Int const&)` -- you'll note the `Int&` is on the *left*.  The left in `(a+b)+c` is a temporary when you add +c.  So it *fails*, because `a=b` won't bind to `Int&`

Finally, there are quirks in how members bind to temporaries.  Because members where added to C++ 20+ years before rvalue/lvalue references where, they'll bind to temporaries far more liberally than  you might expect (by default).

### In more detail:

Your `operator+` member takes a non-const reference on the right hand side.  Your friend takes a non-const reference on the left hand side.

`a+b+c` in C++ is parsed as `(a+b)+c`.  In every case, the right hand side of a `+` has a named value -- an lvalue -- and named mutable values can bind to non-const references.

However, the `+c` has a temporary on the left hand side -- an rvalue -- and temporaries cannot bind to non-const lvalue references.

The final quirk has to do with the fact that a member like this:

```
Int Int::operator + (Int & v)
{
  return Int(a + v.a);
}
```

**can** be called on an rvalue (a temporary), even though it is non-const.  l/r value qualification of objects was added after initial member syntax was.

There are a bunch of ways you are permitted to declare "what kind of object, const or non const, temporary or not, will this method work on".  Their signatures look like:

```
Int operator + (Int const& v);
Int operator + (Int const& v) const;
Int operator + (Int const& v) &;
Int operator + (Int const& v) const&;
Int operator + (Int const& v) &&;
Int operator + (Int const& v) const&&;
```

if you don't include a trailing `&` or a `&&`, your methods bind to **both** rvalues (temporaries) and lvalues (named values with identity).  This is because l/r value references where added 20+ years after methods where added to C++, so the *default* method declaration works with both (for backward compatibility reasons).

```
friend Int operator + (Int &, const Int &);
```

corresponds to

```
Int operator + (const Int &) &;
```

which, as a method, will fail with basically the same error message as the friend does.

You can also induce the

```
friend Int operator + (Int &, Int const&);
```

method to work by typing:

```
a+(b+c)
```

as now the left-hand side of `+c` is a temporary, and refuses to bind to `Int&`.

This will also make the

```
Int operator+(Int&)
```

version fail, as now the right hand side of `a+` is `(b+c)`, which is a temporary, and won't bind to `Int&`.

### General Advice:

When working on operators for a class, do this.

```
Int operator+=(Int const& rhs)&;
```

this is the **increment by** operator.  It should be a member, and it should have the `&` qualification at the end -- incrementing a temporary makes no sense.

Then write:

```
friend Int operator+(Int lhs, Int const& rhs) {
  lhs += rhs;
  return lhs;
}
```

here we use the increment operator to implement `+`.  If our class has efficient move constructors (as it should), this will also be very close to optimal.

The left hand side argument we take by **value**.  We then increment it.  Then we return it (and this implicitly moves).

When you type:

```
a+b+c
```

this becomes

```
(a+b)+c
```

we copy `a` and get:

```
copy of a += b
```

we then move the copy of a into the result.  This is then elided (zero-cost moved) into the left hand argument of `+c`.

We then increment that, and move it to the result.

So, eliminating moves (which should be near zero cost even on most complex objects), we get:

```
Int temporary = a;
temporary += b;
temporary += c;
return temporary;
```

as the result of `a+b+c`.

This pattern works with simple things like fake integers, more complex things like strings, and a myriad of other situations.  And it gives you `+=` and `+` for about the same amount of coding work as typically writing `+` does.

Answer (score 3):

#### Rvalues cannot bind to *non-const* lvalue references

> ```
> friend Int operator + (Int &, const Int &);
> ```

In this signature, the left hand side argument is non-const ref, and rvalues cannot bind to non-const lvalue references to extent their lifetime.

```
   a + b + c;
// ^^^^^ - result: rvalue (temporary)
// -> (rvalue) + c
// -> rvalue cannot bind to non-const lvalue reference.
```

They may, however, bind to const lvalue references to extend their lifetime.

> These two situations seem mostly identical, [...]

An representable example for the member function approach would be to CV- and ref-qualify the member function as non-const lvalue ref:

```
Int operator+(Int &) &;  // ref-qualifier: &
                         // const-qualifier: non (non-const)
```

in which case you will get a similar error as for the `friend` function above.

---

Similarly, the compiling example

> friend Int operator + (Int &, const Int &);

would be comparable to `const` and `&`-qualifying the member function:

```
Int operator+(Int &) const &;
```

as an rvalue `*this` could bind to `const &`, extending its lifetime.

---

#### Exception for non-static member functions with no ref-qualifiers, even though the implicit object parameter may be of non-const lvalue reference type

The reason why the non-ref-qualified case is accepted may come as a surprise, as the type of the implicit object parameter is an lvalue reference if no ref-qualifier is supplied, as per [[over.match.funcs]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.funcs#4): [**emphasis** mine]:

> For non-static member functions, the type of the implicit object parameter is
>
> - “lvalue reference to cv `X`” for functions declared **without a ref-qualifier** or with the & ref-qualifier

However, as covered by [[over.match.funcs]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.funcs#5), this is an explicit exception for the case where no ref-qualifier has been supplied [**emphasis** mine]:

> [...] For non-static member functions **declared without a ref-qualifier, an additional rule applies**:
>
> - even if the implicit object parameter is not const-qualified, **an rvalue can be bound to the parameter** as long as in all other respects the argument can be converted to the type of the implicit object parameter.